# How to dismiss progressDialog in Geocoder

Tags: android, progressdialog

How to dismiss progressDialog in reverse geocoding using geocoder, below are code which i have tried, I have initialised progressDialog in onClick event and trying to dismiss as below

```
private void GetCurrentLocation() {

    gps = new GPSTracker(Example.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        System.out.println(latitude);
        System.out.println(longitude);
        //Get address base on location

        pd.dismiss();

        geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {

            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (null != addresses && addresses.size() > 0) {

                String Location = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();

                if (Location.length() != 0) {

                    txtlocationview.setText(Location);

                } else {
                    txtlocationview.setText("");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        pd.dismiss();
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

}
```

But ProgressDialog is not dismmised

Comment: `ProgressBar` is not a dismissable view. You have set its visibility to `GONE` for it to be hidden.

Comment: Sorry it is progressDialog

Comment: Make sure `ProgressBar` or `ProgressDialog`

Comment: Provide full code

Comment: add `if (pd.isShowing()) {
  pd.dismiss();
}`

Comment: At first debug `ProgressDialog` start point to way

Comment: you are using pd.dismiss() twice in the same scope why is that

Comment: I have tried "if (pd.isShowing()) { pd.dismiss(); }" but it is not working.

Comment: This is how progressDialog has been initialised   Locat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pd = new ProgressDialog(example.this);
                ProgressDialog.show(Shop_Option.this, "", "Loading...", false, true);
                pd.show();
                GetCurrentLocation();
            }
        });

Comment: Provide full code please. Where are you initializing the `ProgressDialog`? Is showing and not dismissing or it just stays on the screen? Are you sure the `dismiss` statement is reachable?

Comment: ProgressDialog is showing but not dismissing..